# How do I show that a MedicalClinic is specialized in a certain HealthCondition or MedicalCondition?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I am trying to create structured data markup that shows that a clinic is specialized in treating a certain health **condition** or health **problem**?

It seems that the only properties available for "MedicalClinic" to specify are "availableService" (types MedicalProcedure, MedicalTest or MedicalProcedure) and "medicalSpecialty" (subtypes Cardiology etc), which doesn't cover this?

Comment: `@MedicalClinic medicalSpecialty @MedicalSpecialty`. The specific triple:  https://schema.org/MedicalClinic https://schema.org/medicalSpecialty https://schema.org/MedicalSpecialty where you enumerate the MedicalSpecialty that you claim to treat.

Comment: The issue is that the enumeration types are limited to medical specialties. But there are clinics that are multidisciplinary (in terms of the backgrounds /disciplines of the doctors on board) but focus solely on a specific health condition. I.e. a burn and wound center would have plastic surgery, dermatology, surgery, infectious disease specialists, orthopedic surgeons, etc. yet focus solely on burn care. I would like to mark up the center as specializing in burn care, as that is what is most appropriate.

Comment: Create your own enumeration following existing examples. Use an array for multidisciplinary items.
An alternative is to create `@WebPage` for each specialty, and then use the property `specialty` to link either/or `@Thing` (detailed) or `@CreativeWork` where you explain the specialty.
Another approach is to link `@MedicalSpecialty` to `@CreativeWork` using `mainEntityOfPage` and then explain the specialty in detail.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like what I am looking for. Sorry to ask for further clarification, but would you be able to point/link to a good existing sample of a new enumeration done this way? I have trouble finding one.

Comment: It's a schema IRI with your specific term. Just be sure to use the correct subtype. https://schema.org/Enumeration. In other words, you are customizing the enumeration subtype with your specific term. Then use `name` and/or `identifier` to disambiguate.

Comment: This SO question might be somewhat relevant for some additional info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66001394/specifying-medicalspecialty-in-schema-org-for-medicalwebpage/66785243#66785243